# move button to the next line when there is no

Tags: android, view, menu, android-custom-view

I need to implement menu that can't be GridView or ListView. Items are next to each other and if there is no place, items should be display in next line as is visible on picture
[image: this is effect that I wanna achieve]

I started implementation that is based on SpannableString and ReplacementSpan, but it supports only basic styling and I have problem with selected state.

What's the best way to implement such menu?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you

```
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Sherif 
 * Updated by Karim Varela to handle LinearLayouts with other views on either side.
 * @param linearLayout
 * @param views : The views to wrap within LinearLayout
 * @param context
 * @param extraView : An extra view that may be to the right or left of your LinearLayout.
 * @author Karim Varela
 **/
private void populateViews(LinearLayout linearLayout, View[] views, Context context, View extraView)
{
    extraView.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // kv : May need to replace 'getSherlockActivity()' with 'this' or 'getActivity()'
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    int maxWidth = display.getWidth() - extraView.getMeasuredWidth() - 20;

    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(context);
    newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    int widthSoFar = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++)
    {
        LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(context);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        views[i].measure(0, 0);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(views[i].getMeasuredWidth(), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);

        LL.addView(views[i], params);
        LL.measure(0, 0);
        widthSoFar += views[i].getMeasuredWidth();
        if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth)
        {
            linearLayout.addView(newLL);

            newLL = new LinearLayout(context);
            newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LL.getMeasuredWidth(), LL.getMeasuredHeight());
            newLL.addView(LL, params);
            widthSoFar = LL.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
        else
        {
            newLL.addView(LL);
        }
    }
    linearLayout.addView(newLL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but finally I use android-flowlayout

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered library called Android flow layout that works well https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout